# Administering user accounts on an ftp server remotely via script, webservice or similar

Tags: scripting, ftp

We want to be able to create FTP users and assign rights to specific folders and revoke them again remotely by means of an automated process (running a script, calling a webservice or similar).

What solutions can you suggest?

OS is undecided. Windows and Unix are both fine.

Comment: What OS?  Any other requirements for the FTP server?

Comment: Edited question to answer OS requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Filezilla FTP Server](http://filezilla-project.org/) has a remote administration tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest pureftpd or proftpd with a mysql backend

Old tutorials but still relevant:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/proftpd_mysql_virtual_hosting
- http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-hosting-with-proftpd-and-mysql-ubuntu-8.04

With this you could use any popular programming language to update the mysql database to your liking including quotas, access, etc.

Alternatively I would recommend glftpd

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glftpd

The setup for glftpd can be quite complicated but it supports a lot of scripting, including user management through ftp commands.